# How do you make Mouse Activated Text?

Tags: support

In Puzzling, it is popular to make text hidden until the user puts their mouse above the yellow area. How do you create this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a "spoiler", and you do it by putting >! at the start of each line.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted

Comment: Note: after the first line it is only required to place the exclamation marks